# What does the 'new' keyword before the parameter list mean in a typscript arrow function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, higher-order-components

I'm pretty new to TypeScript or even JavaScript for that matter. And I've been trying to wrap my head around an example from Microsoft on how to integrate AzureAD authentication in a react app. The example uses an HOC to provide authentication to a component. The declaration for the HOC looks like this:

```
function withAuthProvider<T extends React.Component<AuthComponentProps>>(
    WrappedComponent: new (props: AuthComponentProps, context?: any) => T
): React.ComponentClass {...}
```

Most of it is more or less clear. What puzzles me is the type of `WrappedComponent`. Specifically I don't understand what the `new` keyword does in that context.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a constructor type. It means that when you invoke it with `new`, you can give it a `props` argument and an optional `context` argument, and it'll construct an instance of type `T`.

Here's an example:

```
class Foo {
    private value: number;
    constructor(x: number, y: number = 1) {
        this.value = x + y;
    }
}

const foo: new (arg1: number, arg2?: number) => Foo = Foo;
// can be invoked like this (with new)
const x1: Foo = new foo(1);
const x2: Foo = new foo(1, 2);
// cannot be invoked without new
// these lines will error at both compile- and run-time
const y1: Foo = foo(1);
const y2: Foo = foo(1, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you mind elaborating a bit on the subject? What do you mean by 'invoke with new'? The way this is invoked in the example is this: `class App extends React.Component {...} ... export default withAuthentication(App)`. Does the signature mean, that the class you pass it has to have a construction that accepts a `props: AuthComponentProps` and optionally the `context`? Is there another way to invoke that function?

Comment: Ah I see, you meant that what is passed as param would be invoked with `new`. I thought I could do sth like `const comp = new withAuthentication(props)`. Thank you!